# iTextSharp generate PDF and show it on the browser directly

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

How to open the PDF file after created using iTextSharp on ASP.Net? I don't want to save it on the server, but directly **when the new PDF is generated, it shows on the browser**. Is it possible to do that?

Here is the example for what I mean: [Click here](http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=download) . But on this example, the file directly downloaded.

How can I do that?

```
    Dim doc1 = New Document()

    'use a variable to let my code fit across the page...
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("PDFs")
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, New FileStream(path & "/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create))

    doc1.Open()
    doc1.Add(New Paragraph("My first PDF"))
    doc1.Close()
```

The code above do save the PDF to the server.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem solved with the code below:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)

    pdfDoc.Open()
    'WRITE PDF <<<<<<

    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("My first PDF"))

    'END WRITE PDF >>>>>
    pdfDoc.Close()

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

Hope help! :)

Comment: @ mrjimoy.how to open it in new tab...currently open in same tab so that the web page is replaced and cannot go bak...

Answer (score 6):

You need to set `Content Type` of the `Response object` and add the `binary` form of the `pdf` in the `header`

```
 private void ReadPdfFile()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Somefile.pdf";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer =  client.DownloadData(path);

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
            Response.AddHeader("content-length",buffer.Length.ToString()); 
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer); 
        }

    }
```

(or) you can use `System.IO.MemoryStream` to read and display:

Here you can find that way of doing it

[Open Generated pdf file through code directly without saving it onto the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761007/open-generated-pdf-file-through-code-directly-without-saving-it-onto-the-disk)

Comment: So it means I still should have to save the PDF to the server and then read it?