# a page can have only one server-side form tag, when trying to export file

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am trying to export my `HTML` page to `pdf`

This is the error message I am getting:

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

This is the method:

```
public void pdf_btn_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    }
```

As you can see it fires when a button is clicked

This is HTML:

```
   <form id="export_form" runat="server">
        <div id="buttons_conteiner">
            <asp:Button runat="server" id='export_pdf' OnClick='pdf_btn_clicked' Text="Pdf" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

There no other form on page and there is no master page involved...

any ideas ??

Comment: `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` does not do what you think it does.  You need to save it to the response stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Response.End()` to prevent ASP.Net from rendering the rest of your page.

Answer (score 2):

You're rendering the entire page and then writing the PDF to the output. Of course, that's going to add another form with runat="server".

Solution is don't render the entire page, render a subcontrol within the form.

Also, double check how you're sending the PDF to the client. See [iTextSharp Generate PDF  in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462853/itextsharp-generate-pdf-and-show-it-on-the-browser-directly).

Also, I recommend not rendering a control for its HTML and then sending the results into a PDF. If you need to update the markup for the page, it may mess with how your PDF turns out and vice versa. It's usually better to custom write some HTML for the PDF (or use the traditional way of generating a PDF with iTextSharp).

Comment: @SLaks Good catch, didn't see that at the top of the function. Edited the answer.